# Why doesn't the DeepLink helper launch my Android app?

Tags: actions-on-google

My app is based on this code sample from Google: https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_question.deeplink.html

Here is a snippet directly from my code:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('Great! Looks like we can do that in the app.')
  conv.ask(new DeepLink({
    destination: 'MyBookApp',
    url: 'https://www.mybooksite.com/read/123456789',
    package: 'com.mybook.app.reader',
    reason: 'handle this for you',
  }))
})

// Create a Dialogflow intent with the `actions_intent_LINK` event
app.intent('Get Link Status', (conv, input, arg, status) => {
  // possibly do something with status
  conv.close('Okay maybe we can take care of that another time.')
})
```

When I run this app I see "*Okay maybe we can take care of that another time.*" instead of my app being launched.

Is there code missing in my handler for the '**Get Link Status**' intent? (I created the intent according to the comment above that line).

Am I passing the wrong params to the `DeepLink` object? I can't find docs for them anywhere.

Note: My app is definitely coded to handle `http` deep links including verification with Google Digital Asset Links and the deep link URL I'm testing with works perfectly from other apps.

Any suggestions or help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Your welcome intent handler is missing an additional call to conv.ask before the deep link call:

```
conv.ask('Great! Looks like we can do that in the app.')
```

All responses should have at least a simple response.

Comment: Thank you but I already tried it that way too. I only removed it because it wasn't outputting anyway. No matter what I do I always get "Okay maybe we can take care of that another time."